# Como chamar um método não definido na classe abstrata e sim na classe que a herda

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Suponhamos que existe uma classe e em seu construtor é necessário chamar uma função que só é definida em classes que a herdam. O que é necessário para isso acontecer?

Código de exemplo:

```
interface A {
    public function hello();
}

abstract class B implements A {
    public function __contruct() {
        if (method_exists($this, "hello"))
        {
            $this->hello();
        }
    }
}


class C extends B {
    public function __contruct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function hello() {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }
}

$B = new C();
```

Esse código não retorna nada, mas deveria retornar "Hello World!".

PS: Pensei em métodos abstratos, mas também não obtive o retorno esperado.

Comment: você criou um regra de implementação e não implementou na classe! dá um erro isso ai.

Comment: outro problema `hello()` é um método da classe C não dá classe B! tem problema também, ou seja, se está fazendo algo que não entende.

Comment: tem também erro de digitação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome do método de construção da classe está faltando um `s` que é `construct`, mas, o correto é você implementar o método `hello` dentro da classe `B` porque é ela que implementa a `interface`, preste atenção nisso.

```
<?php

interface A 
{
    public function hello();
}

abstract class B implements A 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        if (method_exists($this, "hello"))
        {
            $this->hello();
        }
    }
    public function hello() 
    {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }
}


class C extends B 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

$B = new C();
```

Não sei bem o que deseja fazer, mas, é bem estranho tudo isso, se você determina que a sua classe implemente uma `interface` isso deve ser seguido, é um regra e deve ser feito assim, agora os motivos que os levou a fazer isso pode ser bem questionável.

Comment: Peço desculpas, a função `oi` era para ser `hello`.. Esqueci de alterar enquanto escrevia a questão.

Comment: No seu caso se mudou isso é porque tem erro de digitação é `construct` com `s`... o resto vai funcionar: https://ideone.com/HiIw6E @ViníciusLara

Comment: Oh jesus. Apagaria a questão, mas né... Obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Comment: Eu edite a resposta, o que você fez não é correto @ViníciusLara ... a implementação deve ser feito na classe que está o `implements`

Comment: Entendo. Qual seria a solução mais correta para isso? Eu preciso que a classe pai consiga exibir o hello world definido pela classe filha.. mas eu não posso fazer essa comunicação pelo controller da classe filha

Comment: eu implementei como deveria ser @ViníciusLara está na resposta... agora se tem um problema tem que postar o seu problema real ...

Answer (score 1):

Esse código não deveria retornar `Hello World!`.

Você não pode chamar um método desconhecido, ou seja, não pode chamar um método que não existe na própria classe. Mesmo que tecnicamente fosse possível não faz sentido conceitualmente e seria um erro de lógica.

Além disso está chamando em um método estático (sim, o construtor é um método estático), um método de instância, então ele não sabe o que chamar.

Não sei se é o que deseja, mas é o que dá para fazer (tirei a interface porque ela não tem a ver com o problema, e se tiver a pergunta não mal definida):

```
abstract class B {
    public function do() {
        $this->hello();
    }
    abstract public function hello();
}


class C extends B {
    public function hello() {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }
}

$B = new C();
echo $B->do();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nhqQvR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/imghmqbg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/AbstractMethod.php).